# Force seconds to be zero

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following datetime64 format `date` column in a data frame `df`

`2018-12-11 15:26:07`

How can I round the seconds to the closests minute in Python to have it like this?

`2018-12-11 15:26:00`

Thanks

Comment: `lambda dt: datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour, dt.minute, tzinfo = dt.tzinfo)`

Comment: Do you really want to round or truncate?   So, what if your value is `2018-12-11 15:27:59` do you want `2018-12-11 15:28:00` rounding or `2018-12-11 15:27:00`?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Series.dt.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html) with a minutely frequency:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['2018-12-11 15:26:07',
                         '2018-12-11 15:26:31']})
df['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df['a'])
df['a'] = df['a'].dt.round('min')
print(df)

#                     a
# 0 2018-12-11 15:26:00
# 1 2018-12-11 15:27:00
```

Comment: Or maybe `s.dt.floor(freq='min')
`

Answer (score 0):

***Creation of df(Dataframe):***

1- Imported `pandas` library in console(In my case Jupyter) by running following command.

```
import pandas as pd
```

2- Now run following command for creating `df`(dataframe).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['2018-12-11 15:26:07',
                         '2018-12-11 15:26:31']})
```

***Now coming on OP's requirement to get the seconds field `00`:***

```
df['a']=df['a'].str.replace(':[0-9]+$', ':00')
df
```

When we print the `df` now, output will be as follows.

```
     a
0   2018-12-11 15:26:00
1   2018-12-11 15:26:00
```

Answer (score -1):

The fastest and simplest way to do this is to redefine the time unit or change the format, from:

```
df['IDENTIFY_DATE'] = df.IDENTIFY_DATE.astype(
    'datetime64[ns]'
```

to:

```
df['IDENTIFY_DATE'] = df.IDENTIFY_DATE.astype(
    'datetime64[s]'
```

unit : string, default ‘ns’ : unit of the arg (D,s,ms,us,ns) denote the unit, which is an integer or float number. This will be based off the origin. Example, with unit=’ms’ and origin=’unix’ (the default), this would calculate the number of milliseconds to the unix epoch start.

Or change the format

```
df['IDENTIFY_DATE'] = df.IDENTIFY_DATE.astype(
    format=“%d/%m/%Y %H:%M”, note that “%f” will parse all the way up to nanoseconds.'
```

format : string, default None
strftime to parse time, eg “%d/%m/%Y”, note that “%f” will parse all the way up to nanoseconds.

Via: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Also helpful: http://strftime.org/

Answer (score -1):

This can work.

```
import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from time import gmtime, strftime
date = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y ")
currenttime = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
ts = time.strftime("%p")
secon = time.strftime("%S")
minut = time.strftime("%M")
hou = time.strftime("%I")

second = int(secon)
minute = int(minut)
hour = int(hou)
newtime = []
if second> 30:
    minute += 1
    if minute > 59:
        minute = 0
        hour += 1
        if hour == 13:
            hour = 1
            newtime.append(str(hour))
            newtime.append(":")
            newtime.append(str(minute))
            newtime.append(":")
            newtime.append(str(0))
            newtime.append(str(0))
            newtime.append(ts)
            currenttime = "".join(newtime)

            fulldate = date + currenttime
            print(fulldate)
        elif hour == 24:
            hour = 0
            ts = "AM"
            newtime.append(str(hour))
            newtime.append(":")
            newtime.append(str(minute))
            newtime.append(":")
            newtime.append(str(0))
            newtime.append(str(0))
            newtime.append(ts)
            currenttime = "".join(newtime)

            fulldate = date + currenttime
            print(fulldate)
        else:
            newtime.append(str(hour))
            newtime.append(":")
            newtime.append(str(minute))
            newtime.append(":")
            newtime.append(str(0))
            newtime.append(str(0))
            newtime.append(ts)
            currenttime = "".join(newtime)

            fulldate = date + currenttime
            print(fulldate)
    else:
        newtime.append(str(hour))
        newtime.append(":")
        newtime.append(str(minute))
        newtime.append(":")
        newtime.append(str(0))
        newtime.append(str(0))
        newtime.append(ts)
        currenttime = "".join(newtime)

        fulldate = date + currenttime
        print(fulldate)
elif second < 30:
    newtime.append(str(hour))
    newtime.append(":")
    newtime.append(str(minute))
    newtime.append(":")
    newtime.append(str(0))
    newtime.append(str(0))
    newtime.append(ts)
    currenttime = "".join(newtime)

    fulldate = date + currenttime
    print(fulldate)
```